# How to add attributes without value when dynamically generating elements with jQuery append?

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to append a script element to my DOM:

```
$("body").append($("<script />", {
    src: "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<?php echo $block->getGoogleTagManagerId(); ?>",
    async: true
}));
```

This adds the script like this:

```
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xyz" async="async"></script>
```

I was expecting this:

```
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xyz" async></script>
```

Are both ways identical ? Will both work?

I worked around it by setting it like this:

```
$("body").append($("<script />", {
    src: "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<?php echo $block->getGoogleTagManagerId(); ?>",
    id: "googletagmanager_script"
}));
$("#googletagmanager_script").prop("async", true);
```

But does it even make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're equivalent. `async` is a boolean attribute. To make it true, you just add it to the element, and the value is not really significant.

> If a boolean attribute is present, its value is true, and if it's absent, its value is false.
>
> HTML5 defines restrictions on the allowed values of boolean attributes: If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string (equivalently, the attribute may have an unassigned value), or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

But for backward compatibility, browsers generally don't enforce this restriction.

jQuery uses the form of `attribute="attribute"` as its canonical format when it creates boolean attributes with `true` values. If you want just `attribute`, you can use an empty string as the value:

```
$("body").append($("<script />", {
    src: "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<?php echo $block->getGoogleTagManagerId(); ?>",
    async: ""
}));
```

Comment: I tested it with `async: ""` but it still gives me `async='async'`. But at least it makes no difference.

Comment: I tested in Chrome by checking the outerHTML of the element that was created and it just showed `async`.